# How to convert lookAtPoint in ARKit to screen points?

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit, eye-tracking

I am trying to convert the lookAtPoint property in ARKit into to screen points.
I mean, I want to show a red dot wherever I look into the screen.

I tried to use the sceneView.projectPoint method but without any success.

I also tried to use the leftEyeTransform and rightEyeTransform.

I appreciate any help.
Thanks!